# Bucles anidados for para 2 listas Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

buenas noches, soy muy nuevo en esto, es mi primer semana y estoy tratando de hacer un programa en el que ingresas tus calificaciones y te dice cuáles son las que aprobaste y cuáles no. Pero no estoy muy seguro qué estoy haciendo mal y necesito su ayuda.
El código en cuestión es este:

```
materias = ["Matemáticas", "Física", "Química", "Historia", "Lengua"]
notas = []

for materia in materias:
    notas.append(int(input("Ingresa tu calificación en " + materia)))


for nota in notas:
    for materia in materias:
        if nota <= 5:
            print("Debes repetir " + materia)
        else:
            print("Has aprobado " + materia)
```

El resultado es este:

```
Ingresa tu calificación en Matemáticas8
Ingresa tu calificación en Física6
Ingresa tu calificación en Química8
Ingresa tu calificación en Historia5
Ingresa tu calificación en Lengua3
Has aprobado Matemáticas
Has aprobado Física
Has aprobado Química
Has aprobado Historia
Has aprobado Lengua
Has aprobado Matemáticas
Has aprobado Física
Has aprobado Química
Has aprobado Historia
Has aprobado Lengua
Has aprobado Matemáticas
Has aprobado Física
Has aprobado Química
Has aprobado Historia
Has aprobado Lengua
Debes repetir Matemáticas
Debes repetir Física
Debes repetir Química
Debes repetir Historia
Debes repetir Lengua
Debes repetir Matemáticas
Debes repetir Física
Debes repetir Química
Debes repetir Historia
Debes repetir Lengua
```

Honestamente soy un poco malo en esto pero sé que con práctica y persistencia mejoraré, así que agradezco mucho sus comentarios.

Comment: Sin relación en sí con el código: ¿seguro que tienes que "repetir" si sacas un 5? ¿no sería más correcto que la comparación fuera `nota < 5` para repetir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por cada comparación de nota estás repitiendo todas las materias y como nota no cambia hasta que haya recorrido todas las materias, por eso el mensaje sale repetido.

Se resolvería con un solo ciclo `for`, ya que depende exactamente del orden de las materias (esto va a partir desde el segundo `for`)

```
i = 0
for materia in materias:
    if notas[i] <= 5:
        print("Debes repetir " + materia)
    else:
        print("Has aprobado " + materia)
    i +=1
```

Lo mismo se puede escribir aún mucho mejor:

```
for i, materia in enumerate(materias):
    if notas[i] <= 5:
        print("Debes repetir " + materia)
    else:
        print("Has aprobado " + materia)
```

Ahora bien, el principal problema aquí es que son dos estructuras de datos (listas) que no tienen que ver una con la otra. En la vida real pudieras tener pérdidas de coherencia de datos. Para resolverlo mejor, no se si has llegado allá, se puede con diccionarios, creando una estructura de datos con esta forma:

```
notas = {'materia1':nota1, 'materia2':nota2, ...}
```

Llevando ese concepto a código:

```
materias = ["Matemáticas", "Física", "Química", "Historia", "Lengua"]
notas = {}

for materia in materias:
    notas[materia] = int(input("Ingresa tu calificación en " + materia))

for materia, nota in notas.items():
    if nota <= 5:
        print("Debes repetir " + materia)
    else:
        print("Has aprobado " + materia)
```

Comment: Gracias, hermano, probé con todas las opciones y efectivamente todas funcionaron.  Debo seguir estudiando estructuras de datos y bucles.