# Entrada de datos mediante lista en python

Tags: python, lista, input

estoy tratando de generar un programa que pida datos al usuario y devuelva un respuesta como el siguiente:

```
    nombre = input('Ingrese su nombre: )
    id = input('Ingrese su cedula de estudiante: )
    calificación = input('Ingrese su calificación: )

    if calificación < 8:
       print('Estas aprobado')
    else:
       print('Estas aprobado')
```

Ahora bien mi programa funciona bien, pero si yo quisiera en vez de ingresar uno por uno ingresar mediante una lista como sería para analizar varios datos, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Resolví un problema muy similar [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/511599/80870), solo varía la calificacion de 5 a 8.

Answer (score 2):

no se exactamente que es lo que necesitas. Hice un programa que sirve para pedir unas listas al usuario con la diferente información necesaria (no esta controlado, es decir que no he controlado si metes mas nombres que id etc pero eso se podría hacer con un `len()`) Tras pedir la información simplemente hice un bucle for para que escriba la información que recogió en las listas.

MÉTODO DE USO: para meter listas por input vas escribiendo lo que te pida y enter si quieres parar de meter nombres simplemente dale a lo que te diga el print().

Añado: cuidado con tu programa porque en tu if tienes puesto dos veces aprobado y arriba en un input te falta una '

Un saludo espero que te sirva.

```
tu_nombre = []
tu_id = []
las_calificaciones = []

nombre = str(input('Ingrese su nombre (Escribe la letra: e para finalizar)'))

while nombre != 'e':
    tu_nombre.append(nombre)
    nombre = str(input(''))

id = int(input('Ingrese su cedula de estudiante: (Escribe el numero: 0 para finalizar)'))
while id != 0:
    tu_id.append(id)
    id = int(input(''))

calificacion = int(input('Ingrese su calificación: (Escriba el numero: 11 para finalizar)'))
while calificacion != 11:
    las_calificaciones.append(calificacion)
    calificacion = int(input(''))

for i in range(0, len(tu_nombre)):
    if las_calificaciones[i] < 8:
        print(tu_nombre[i], ', con cedula de estudiante:', tu_id[i], ': estas suspenso')
    else:
        print(tu_nombre[i], 'Con cedula de estudiante: ', tu_id[i], ': estas aprobado')
```

Función para pedir al usuario hasta que escriba lo que tu quieras

```
nombre = str(input('Ingrese su nombre (Escribe la letra: e para finalizar)'))

while nombre != 'e':
    tu_nombre.append(nombre)
    nombre = str(input(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Agregue una lista al principio donde irían las materias correspondientes, y luego antes de preguntar por la calificación un bucle for para que vaya asignatura por asignatura preguntando la nota

```
materias = ["Lenguaje","Matemáticas","Naturaleza","Artes"]
nombre = input('Ingrese su nombre: ')
id = input('Ingrese su cedula de estudiante: ')

for i in materias:
    
    calificacion = float(input(f'Ingrese su calificación en {i}: '))
    if calificacion < 8:
        print('Estas aprobado')
    else:
        print('Estas aprobado')
```

Comment: Agrego que no es buena practica crar variables que se llamen igual que un built-in en python. Ya que al asignar dichas variables reemplazas la funcion built-in original. Por que digo esto? Por que id es una funcion built-in...